# Is there any JS smart json schema validator, like Joi maybe, but with dynamic custom errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, schema, joi

I want to easily validate user's input.

When I ask the first name of the user (for example), it can take tons of lines of code in order to really make it good validated.

I want something that I can use in front end and either in back end - without changing the validation structure.

I need the ability to throw custom detailed errors, something like this:

```
let schema = Joi.object.keys({
  first_name: Joi.string("Required to be a string")
  .noNumbers("Should not contain numbers")
  .minlenth(2, "At least 2 chars")
  .maxlength(10, "Maximum 10 chars")
  .required("Required field"),
  last_name: Joi.string("Required to be a string")
  .noNumbers("Should not contain numbers")
  .minlenth(2, "At least 2 chars")
  .maxlength(10, "Maximum 10 chars")
  .required("Required field"),
});
```

Unfortunately the above does not work - since Joi does not work like this.

Maybe is there a good JSON schema validator to easily and efficiently validate the user's input without wasting time - and yet keep it clear for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOI. In the following example I'm overriding the errors directly :

```
   return Joi.object()
      .keys({
        str: Joi.string()
          .min(2)
          .max(10)
          .required()
          .error(errors => errors.map((err) => {
            const customMessage = ({
              'string.min': 'override min',
              'string.max': 'override max',
            })[err.type];

            if (customMessage) err.message = customMessage;

            return err;
          })),
      });
```

---

I recommand you to use a function, considering the errors messages are going to be the same for all request :

```
function customErrors(errors) {
   return errors.map((err) => {
        const customMessage = ({
             'string.min': 'override min',
             'string.max': 'override max',
        })[err.type];

        if (customMessage) err.message = customMessage;

       return err;
   });
}

return Joi.object()
    .keys({
      str: Joi.string()
           .min(2)
           .max(10)
           .required()
           .error(customErrors),
      });
```

---

**EDIT :**

```
// This

const customMessage = ({
  'string.min': 'override min',
  'string.max': 'override max',
})[err.type];

if (customMessage) err.message = customMessage;


// Equals this

let customMessage = false;

if (err.type === 'string.min') customMessage = 'override min';
if (err.type === 'string.max') customMessage = 'override max';

if (customMessage) err.message = customMessage;


// Equals this

if (err.type === 'string.min') err.message = 'override min';
if (err.type === 'string.max') err.message = 'override max';
```

Comment: So far this is just awesome answer. I will give it a try and let you know. Where can I find a full reference of the `context` key?

Comment: All the documentation I have is [this](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.0.0/API.md#anyerrorerr)

Comment: The `customMessage` variable is using ES6 features for simple and quick `if statement` replacer? If then - how does it named?